# What does "+=" to a PropertyChangedEventHander mean?

Tags: c#

In the following code example, Model.PropertyChanged is a "System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHander". What does " += (s,e) => {...}" mean?

```
            Model.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.PropertyName == Friend.FirstNamePropertyName
                    || e.PropertyName == Friend.LastNamePropertyName)
                {
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => FullName);
                    return;
                }

                if (e.PropertyName == Friend.DateOfBirthPropertyName)
                {
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => DateOfBirthFormatted);
                }
            };
```

Comment: I guest it is trying to assign function delegate to PropertyChanged event by using lambda expression? s usually represent the sender as object, and e usually represent an event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Model.PropertyChanged` is an **[event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx)** to which you can subscribe one or more event handlers. You can add an event handler with `+=` and remove a handler with `-=`.

The `+= (s, e) => { ... }` syntax is declaring a lambda expression as a delegate for an inline event handler for the event. Using a lambda expression is a concise way of declaring an event handler inline for the event.

The `s` and the `e` parameters are strongly typed parameters that can be inferred by the compiler via the signature of the `PropertyChangedEventHandler` delegates that can subscribe to the event. They refer to `Object` and `PropertyChangedEventArgs` types, respectively, as per the signature of the [`PropertyChangedEventHandler` delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
[HostProtectionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, SharedState = true)]
public delegate void PropertyChangedEventHandler(
    Object sender,
    PropertyChangedEventArgs e
)
```

Answer (score 3):

An event can have multiple handlers.  Using `+=` adds a handler to a particular event.  The `(s,e) =>` syntax is used to create an anonymous function rather then defining a class method and assigning it as a handler:

```
Model.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged(object s, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == Friend.FirstNamePropertyName
        || e.PropertyName == Friend.LastNamePropertyName)
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => FullName);
        return;
    }

    if (e.PropertyName == Friend.DateOfBirthPropertyName)
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => DateOfBirthFormatted);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

**+=** is a subscription syntax for an Event. The reverse of it (*unsubscription*) would be **-=**.

Read more of it at this link: [Event Subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

its an addition operator

**[+= Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx)**

so, `Model.PropertyChanged` could have multiple suscriptions of an event handler.

More info:

**[How to: Subscribe to and Unsubscribe from Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, `Model.PropertyChanged` is an event.

In .Net, events are MultiCast (special type of MultiCastDelegates).

Multiple subscribers can subscribe to an event, by adding a new handler / delegate (to existing list of subscribers).

The handler can be an anonymous `delegate` as well.

An appropriate `lambda` can be used, instead of a `delegate` (as long as signatures match).

Hence, what you see above, is an event, to which an event handler is being added, using a lambda expression.